# How to decode html entity in mongo db query?

Tags: mongodb-query

As I am writing mongo shell scripts. I blocked in decoding the html entities.

I wanted to know how to decode html entity such as `(" &reg ;", " &trade ;") into ®, ™` using mongo db query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if i understand correctly you want to query `TM`  etc in mongo query right? i dont know if this will work but you can open a document where they are saved and see how they are saved and copy- paste in query object.
 you can alternatively use js `eval(&trade ;)` when querying

Comment: eval is not working in mongo query